# Jenkins - change title of main page

Tags: jenkins, start-page

How can I change the title in the Jenkins start page:
http://jenkinsserver.domain.whatever:9090/

As I see, the title is already in German with some special UTF-8 chars and this one makes trouble using selenium in the background to control Jenkins. I am quite sure the value is set somewhere - but where?

Jenkins runs on a Windows server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just install the [Simple Theme Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin) and then in **Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Theme**, point the *URL of theme JS* field to a .js file containing at minimum something like:

```
document.title = "Wathever title you prefer";
```

Save and reload the page.

It worked for me..

Comment: And then in Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Theme 

point it to the url:

http://<jenkins url>/userContent/my-style.<js | css>

Comment: ximbal comment should really go in the answer, because the very next question someone is likely to ask, is "where should i put the script"

Comment: For others who just want to customize the title per server, not nuke it and start over, perhaps something like `document.title = "<Your Hostname> " + document.title;`

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is using the browser locale language settings, change that. Please also better specify the question, what do you mean by title? Local domain address? If so, this can be done in settings -> "Jenkins URL".

Comment: With title I mean the content in the HTML-TAG title of the main page. In my case (german) it contains 

Übersicht [Jenkins]

This one I want to change. I found some translation beneth help/.. but none of them contains those value.

So I am looking for perhaps an config value in one of the xml-files?!?

Comment: Adding some js to the system message in the configure system field used to work, for example:

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
document.title = "Test Jenkins";
</SCRIPT>

but since 1.459 it doesn't work anymore.